# Sharing session with just the "www" subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, subdomain

I have faced this issue time and again, when ever I set up a new site/virtual host, I have to go and set the session domain ( or the framework equivalent ) to ".example.com" so that the session can be shared b/w "www.example.com" and "example.com".

What this does is it messes the cookies for my staging and qa environments ( something like qa.example.com ..etc ).

Whats the solution to this ? Should I setup a rewrite rule so that all www.example.com requests are rewritten to "example.com" or is there some other way ?

I want to find out if there is a framework/language specific solution to this, what do people do when facing such an issue, whats the standard ?

Comment: from where does this get ruby-on-rails tag? :-/

Comment: Well uDaY.. Like I said, Framework equivalent of session domain. I want to find out if there is a framework specific solution to this, because I code in rails most of the time. I ll be happy with just that solution.

Comment: Clear cookies a viable solution? :)

Comment: @sberry well that does work :) , but generally devs will be looking at multiple environments at the same time, it can be really annoying everytime I switch to looking at staging to production I need to clear my cookies, just because I have a generic session domain

Answer (score 1):

> Whats the solution to this ? Should I setup a rewrite rule so that all www.example.com requests are rewritten to "example.com" or is there some other way?

As most programming problems, there is not just ONE solution for this. What I did to face this exact problem is to set up a rewrite rule as you stated and working with subdirectories. It gives less headaches, but at some points you might require subdomains, it all depends on your needs. So, if you can work with `example.com/qa` instead of `qa.example.com`, I'd go (and went) for it. I used this:

```
#Redirect any www. to the page without it. Helps to keep user logged.
RewriteEngine On
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org [NC]
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> I want to find out if there is a framework/language specific solution to this, what do people do when facing such an issue, whats the standard ?

Sorry, I cannot help you with this 2nd part as I don't know any standard to do it the other way. Hope someone can complete the answer.